# Function pointer assignment

Tags: c

In the following code, I am having few questions:

1. How does the function name without `&` symbol give the address value of the function? Is this due to compiler intelligence? or is this allowable c syntax?
2. Is it possible to reuse name `fun` for any variable declaration? Should any linker demangling be done to achieve this?

```
void fun(int a) 
{ 
    printf("Value of a is %d\n", a); 
}  

int main() 
{  
    void (*fun_ptr)(int) = fun;  
    fun_ptr(10);   
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You should assign the function pointer with "fun_ptr = &fun;", then call with: "(*fun_ptr)(10);"

Comment: The linker is only concerned with global names. Local variables like `fun_ptr` do not affect linking.

Comment: @SPlatten the original code is fine

Comment: @M.M, search for a function pointer and the correct way to call it, that syntax shown is not what I would use.

Comment: @SPlatten `fun_ptr(10);` is the correct way. Your suggestion is just redundant operators . Look up the function call operator in the C Standard, it literally says the left expression should be a pointer to function.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer), because of function to pointer conversion, using `&` is not necessary for function pointers:

```
void f(int);
void (*pf1)(int) = &f;
void (*pf2)(int) = f; // same as &f
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions, like arrays, naturally decays to pointers. Using `fun` when a pointer to a function is expected causes the compiler to treat it as `&fun`.

And no you can't use `fun` as the variable name, as that will *hide* the function by the same name, meaning you can't use the function `fun` (as in that scope all uses of `fun` references the variable). This hiding happens in compilation.

Answer (score 0):

It is a defined part of the C language that a function designator (that's what you have when you use `fun` in an expression) that is *not* the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof` or unary-`&` operators evaluates to a pointer to the function.  So your `void (*fun_ptr)(int) = fun;` declaration is perfectly fine.

`fun` can't be re-used as another declarator at file scope, regardless of whether that's a variable or another function.  You *can* shadow it with a variable declaration in block scope, if you want (this would equally apply to a file-scope variable declaration too).